# Can you create a stationary/standing wave with two vibrating sources?

Tags: waves, interference, superposition

In most textbooks, a typical formation of a stationary wave is from a vibrating source in a medium that has a closed-end on the other side. In which the reflected wave will be coherent, with the same frequency and wavelength as the original wave produced by the vibrating source. But if I were to replace the closed-end with a vibrating source with the same frequency settings producing the same wave, would I produce a stationary wave as well?

Comment: Yes. (It's that simple, as long as there is no quantum mechanics)

Comment: Yes! I recommend you to pick up a rope or better yet a slinky, and try it out with a partner! And try to reach higher harmonics! This will also give you information about the phase relation between the two ends as well.